# Store DataTables API Instance in Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

On a webpage I have the following table:

```
<table id="table1" class="dynamicTable">
...
...
</table>
```

In a JavaScript file added to all of my pages I had the following:

```
$(".dynamicTable").DataTable({ ... });
```

which worked fine. Now, on each page I need to access the DataTables API (initializing DataTables and calling its API are done in different places). I thought it would be a good idea to store the API instance in a property of the table itself, so I changed to this:

```
$(".dynamicTable").each(function () {
    $(this).api = $(this).DataTable({ ... });
});
```

and tried to access it on my page with:

```
$("#table1").api.rows()....
```

but it doesn't work. I tried many other things such as (inside .each() function):

```
$(this).get(0).api = $(this).DataTable({ ... });
```

and:

```
var datatable = {};
datatable.api = $(this).DataTable({ ... });
$.extend($(this), datatable);
```

and so on. Please tell me, how I can store the API instance inside the table itself for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$(this).data("api",$(this).DataTable({ ... }));
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6b74w/400/)**

Comment: AFAIK, .data() sets and gets HTML 5 data- attributes. Right? I am talking about JS objects and prototypes.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy No, **.data()** exists before HTML5. It's after jQuery 1.4.3 that **.data()** starting automatically pulling HTML5 data-attributes. data() method is allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks. It will **work** *almost* everywhere. As you were asking a way to store a value Datatable instance to an element and so that you can retrieve it later on. It is easiest way to do it. visit [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for more info.